# SpringBootTest Integration tests not working well with multiple (@SpringBootApplication)

Tags: spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBootTest integration tests for a certain framework I'm developing which uses jpa which is instatntiated with SpringBootApplication.
I added support to use the framework without jpa and for that I needed to create a different SpringBootApplication which doesn't use jpa.

Now the test classes when run separetly work great, but when I run it all together (Different test classes which run different SpringApplications) the second in order tests classes fail because I seems the context doesn't resets between test classes.

I seperated the test classes by using:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
@SpringBootTest(classes = ClassA.class, webEnviornemt ... etc)
@DirtiesContext (tried all the variations)
@ActiveProfiles("testA")
public class TestsA

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes = ClassB.class, webEnviornemt ... etc)
@DirtiesContext (tried all the variations)
@ActiveProfiles("testB")
public class TestsB
```

if ClassA runs first then class B fails and vice versa..

any suggestions why SpringBootTest wont switch classes?

Comment: I don't see an @RunWith annotation

Comment: @SimonMartinelli my bad.. Edited

Comment: Can you post the exception please?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue again using spring boot 2.5.4, and to be honest I am a little surprised that it is still an issue. So apperantly starting up multiple application contexts is by design, and should not break anything (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23831), but as you have seen it seems a bit buggy at the moment. So until it is "resilent" I normally use one of the following 2 workarounds:

My first workarounds includes always using the same configurations as soon as you use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. For example I just had 2 tests, one was annotated like this `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and the other like this `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` and I could easily switch both to use `RANDOM_PORT`.

My second workaround is to use a different folder for each test, for example where I have a very "expensive" application context, like in our project we have the multi tenant integration tests in the folder `src\multitenanttest`. Once again all of the tests in the folder will use the exact same context as the config is the same for all of the test classes:

```
\\ ...
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Olympia.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ OlympiaProfiles.TEST, OlympiaProfiles.MULTI_TENANT })
public class BillingAddressControllerTest
\\ ...
```

And then in the gradle folder you can create a source set for the new test folder like this (and it's resource folder):

```
// ...

sourceSets {
  multitenanttest {
    java.srcDir "$projectDir/src/multitenanttest/java"
    resources.srcDir "$projectDir/src/multitenanttest/resources"
    compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
    runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
  }
}

configurations {
  multitenanttestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
  multitenanttestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task multitenanttestTest(type: Test) {
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.multitenanttest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.multitenanttest.runtimeClasspath
}

test.dependsOn multitenanttestTest

// ...
```

Now when I run `./gradlew test` everything works as expected, eclipse unfortunately you still have to click on the individual folders.